# Power BI measure that calculates the max based on the count of products, then returns the count of the date the max occurred

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am looking for a measure that calculates the max based on the total of products on each day in the image, identifies the date the max occured and then return the total count of the date the max occured.

CONTEXT:
I have 5 products with following product count at the end of the week.

[Product Count at the end of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okU0d.png)

I use this measure to get the numbers above:

Weekend  Counts =

```
CALCULATE([Total Count],
YEAR(Calendar[Date]) = YEAR(TODAY()),
MONTH(Calendar[Date]) = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, 
Calendar[Day of Week Name] = "Saturday",
'Product Type'[Product Type] ="Total Count"
)
```

I am looking for a measure that calculates the max based on the total of products on each day in the image, identifies the date the max occurred and then return the total count of the date the max occurred.

In this case the max will be 571, the max date that it occurred (29 Apr 2023 in this case) it should then return only counts of the max total dates and not max across each product type

**What i have been able to achieve**

I created this measure to get the max product total across the dates showed above:
MaxColumnTotal =
MAXX(VALUES(Product[Date]), [Weekend  Counts])

Then I created this measure to get the date that the max occured

MaxTotalDate  =
VAR MaxTotal = [MaxColumnTotal]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
MAX(Product[Date]),
FILTER(VALUES(Product[Date]), [Weekend  Counts] = MaxTotal)
)
But now what this gives me is what is in the table below:
[max date retur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00tH6.png)

**What i want to get is this**
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m88B1.png)

Comment: The  products’ column in the visual acts as filter as well. Have a look at ALL() or REMOVEFILTERS() to change that in your measure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the solution to your problem using the Contoso database. You can run it at http://dax.do. It returns the date of max sales for a single customer. This solution uses the new INDEX function. You could also solve this using the TOPN function.

```
var t = ADDCOLUMNS (SUMMARIZE (Sales, Customer[Customer Code], 'Date'[Date]), "@qty", CALCULATE (SUM(Sales[Quantity])))

var toprow = INDEX(1, t, ORDERBY([@qty], DESC, 'Date'[Date], DESC))

RETURN MAXX(toprow, 'Date'[Date])
```